# Как стилизовать угол textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, textarea

Как изменить угол textarea отвечающий за resize?

Comment: А можете привести пример как надо? Ну желательно картинку или хотя бы текст.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13126917/1548895

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov Да самое оно, Спасибо!

Comment: Ни как...  Придется самому реализовать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить - т. е. запретить `resize`?
Если да то вот так:

- **`resize: none` – Размеры элемента не изменяются.**
- `resize: both` – Можно изменять размеры элемента по горизонтали и вертикали.
- `resize: horizontal` - Можно изменять размеры элемента только по горизонтали.
- `resize: vertical` - Можно изменять размеры элемента только по вертикали.
- `resize: inherit` - Наследует значение родителя.

Comment: Думаю, речь идет о внешнем оформлении.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью псевдо-элемента `::-webkit-resizer` можно стилизовать уголок textarea.

Пример

```css
textarea::-webkit-resizer{
   border: 2px solid black;
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px blue;
  outline: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126917/can-i-style-the-resize-grabber-of-textarea